# Debug why header compression isn't working with GRPC

Tags: android, okhttp, grpc

Edit: Initially I confused an SSL token with a JWT token that I create.  With this edit, I have adjusted my initial question below:

I'm using GRPC with java in android.  I'm using the OkHttpChannelBuilder to create a channel with an SSL certificate.  I'm also using a JWT token to authenticate users.  Based on some TCP dump's I've done, I have noticed each tiny request I send includes the full JWT in the header.  My JWT tokens are around 1kb.

Based on my reading, GRPC supports header compression, but I haven't found out how I can turn it on.  I do have control over both client / server, so I can updated either / both if it needs to be enabled on client side / server side.

I'm looking for a guide / instructions on how to debug why header compression isn't being used.  Or I'm looking for explicit instructions on how to turn it on.

Comment: Are you doing client side certs or anything with the trust manager?

Comment: Yes.  client has a certificate it passes to the server with each request.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the cert isn't included in the HTTP header.  SSL is established before HTTP is, so you might be seeing something else.  Can you paste in exactly the bytes you see?

Comment: I agree that the SSL cert isn't included in the header. Are you reusing the ManagedChannel across RPCs? You should share the ManagedChannel as much as possible.

Comment: @Eric and Carl.  You guys are correct.  It's not the SSL certificate.  It's the application token that I use for authentication.  I pack it into each request (coming from client) as a http header.  I was confusing the two systems.

Comment: It's unclear from your question what compression you want to happen.  HTTP/2 does do header compression (using a index into a table), and very slightly using the HPACK Huffman table, but I am just guessing as to what you mean.   Can you clarify?

Comment: @CarlMastrangelo I'm having problem making the hpack compression (creating a managedchannel and not using SSL. If you track the request, all the header is in plain text (not compressed).